# How to get logged user id from database using session in laravel 6

Tags: php, database, laravel, session

I am trying to get logged user id from database using laravel but i am lacking. Please help me to get logged user id from database using session. Thanks in advance

Comment: `use Auth;` then `Auth::user()->id;`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user id by using the `user` method on the Auth facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::user()->id;
```